# Dont know how to wrote php code

Tags: php, variables

I need little simple and quick help with my coding. My problem is that I have the value `1000,2000`, which is stored in

```
$_REQUEST['Number']
```

Then I must read this value and get 2 numbers without ",". 
What code I use for this.

So I have:

```
value = $_REQUEST['Number'];
```

Which is 1000,2000

Now I need:

```
$num1 -> 1000 
$num2 -> 2000
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i have try : $num1.",".$num2 = $_REQUEST['Number'];

Comment: Show us your attempts in your question!

Comment: $numbers = explode(",", $value); which splits the string up and makes the values available as an array, and then $num1= $numbers[0]; $num2 = $numbers[1];

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Here I use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the string into an array and assign the single values with [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

```
list($num1, $num2) = explode(",", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi at the request for your simple and quick help, you can use a method in php called split to split the string, in this case your value variable, by a delimiter of a coma, which is ','. The split method will scan through your string and if it sees a coma it will split the strings and store them into an array. Now these individual split strings, called tokens, will be stored first in a position in the array starting at index / position 0. The first token will be stored at $array[0], in this case 1000, and the second token will be stored at $array[1], in this case 2000.

So if you want the $num1 and $num2 to contain the tokens respectively just assign the values contained in the array into them.

And below is the code:

```
<?php
$value = "1000,2000"; //your string to be split

$array = split (",", $value); //split method takes two parameters, first one is the delimiter by which a string will be split, and the second parameter is the string to be split

$num1 = $array[0]; //now assign value contained in the array at position 0 to the variable $num1
$num2 = $array[1]; //assign value contained in the array at position 1 to the variable $num2
?>
```

Comment: What does the backslash do here, @pythonhiew?

Comment: Hi halfer, sorry it must be a typo but nevertheless it worked. At the requests of both halfer and hichris123 I would now edit my answer. Thanks for reminding.